# Objective-Cの if(test != nil)のような書き方をSwiftにする場合の書き方について

Tags: swift, ios

Objective-Cで記述されている内容をSwiftに移植しています。
Objective-CでのnilをSwift上ではどのように処理してよいかわからず質問いたします。

以下のような書き方をSwiftにする場合はどの様に記述すべきでしょうか。

```
MTLRenderPassDescriptor *testPassDescriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor;

if(testPassDescriptor != nil) {
    NSAssert(@"error: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: Swiftには値がnilになりうるOptional型があるのですから、`if(test != nil)`のような書き方は(`test`がOptional型であれば)Swiftでもそのまま使えるはずです。そのままでは使えないとか、Swift的にいい書き方なのかどうか知りたいとかであれば、コードのごく一部だけ示すのではなく前後関係が十分分かるように十分なコード・情報を示してください。

Answer (score 0):

ご質問内容の修正ありがとうございました。ただ、一番肝心なif分の中身に意味のあることを書いていただいていないので、どう言う書き方にすべきか、どう言う書き方が良いのか、についてはっきりとは言えません。

コメントに書いた「Optional型であれば」が成立するので、普通にObjective-Cと同じように書けます。

```
        let testPassDescriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor
        
        if testPassDescriptor != nil {
            //...
        }
```

(NSAssertについては、私の知らない使い方をしている上にどこにも表れていない変数`error`を使っているので全く意味不明のため省略しました。)